# send data from server and recived data by using php,ajax,javascribt , json , post

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

I need example to clear how can  send data from server and recived data by server , using php,ajax,javascribt , json , post

thank you for all

Comment: there are countless examples of this available online, please do some research and come back if you are stuck with actual code

Comment: I get that he needs to research, but come on, why the downvotes for an answer that gives exactly what he asked for.

Answer (score -3):

A little bit of googling for php ajax post json example returned this excellent example:

http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

HTML:

```
<!--Put the following in the <head>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
        );

        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>

<!--Put the following in the <body>-->
<form class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="favorite_beverage" value="" placeholder="Favorite restaurant" />
  <input type="text" name="favorite_restaurant" value="" placeholder="Favorite beverage" />
  <select name="gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"  />
</form>

<div class="the-return">
  [HTML is replaced when successful.]
</div>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){
  $return = $_POST;

  //Do what you need to do with the info. The following are some examples.
  //if ($return["favorite_beverage"] == ""){
  //  $return["favorite_beverage"] = "Coke";
  //}
  //$return["favorite_restaurant"] = "McDonald's";

  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
  echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you sir 

can be explain this code



var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

Comment: Data is an array of items that you wish to submit as parameters via the url for the post method.  Serialize puts them into appropriate format.  Here you can add all your form fields or whatever you need to pass to PHP.  If this answer, answers your question, I would appreciate it if you marked it as such.  Thank you!

Comment: thank you sir
sir the code not work because need 'return,php'

Comment: The php code I posted, should be put in a file called response.php.  It should be in the same directory as your html file.  Also, remove the action.

Comment: Updated the above code to remove the action.  If that doesn't work, it may just need to be changed from return.php to response.php or whatever your file name is.

Comment: Also, read his full tutorial here:  https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/  This is why many people were upset.  This is a very common application and there are tons of examples out there.  Stack Overflow is designed where you post code, like the above and say help me, something is not working and not help me write all of my code.  I am willing to help someone start coding because it can be daunting, but please do take a bit of time to search SO or google.